# How to convert an existing Django app to run in a virtualenv?

Tags: python, django, virtualenvwrapper

There are so many questions about this, and so many tries I've made and probably bungled...

But let me stick to the real problem: I have a fledgling Django app that I want to insulate from future changes to support software.  I think putting in under a virtual environment is the answer.  I'd like guidance, even just a pointer to the right Howto (one about migrating, not a fresh install).

My environment is Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, apache2, python3.5 and django 2.0.  I'll be upgrading to the next LTS, which is why I want to insulate this app from changes.

Complicating matters is the fact that python2 and python 3 are both here, and pyhton2 is the default (what you get when you just call for "python".   That makes things weird, for instance, because pip3 is uses the default python, so the output of 'pip3 freeze' is very different from what I get when I run it under python3, and I don't know the details of why.

What has failed in the past is my attempts to do it following guidance aimed at a freshly installed OS.  What's more, probably because I did something wrong, pip3 lives in my $HOME/.local/bin/pip3.  I don't know how to undo this.

Comment: as an aside, you can set up your virtual environment to run with python 3 [https://medium.com/@gitudaniel/installing-virtualenvwrapper-for-python3-ad3dfea7c717]

Answer (score 3):

If you have an existing environment that you wish to replicate inside of venv or on another machine inside of venv, then do this command inside your original environment:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

On the other machine or inside the virtual environment ( after having run `path/to/venv/bin/activate` ), do:

```
pip install -r path/to/requirements.txt
```

This should save and then restore your environment.

Comment: Well, yes, that makes the environment.  Now how do I get Apache to serve from that instead of from the native environment?

Comment: [Use apache's `mod_wsgi`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#how-to-use-django-with-apache-and-mod-wsgi) . See directive `WSGIDaemonProcess` to set up the path to your venv directory.